# Why might IE give a wrong result for Math.floor()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, floating-point, rounding

I've got logs from my client-side app which show IE occasionally having trouble with `Math.floor`.

Here's an example of one of these logs:

```
var d = 1442167625975
d / 16 = 90135476623.4375
Math.floor(d / 16) = -58836593
Math.floor = function floor() {
 [native code]
}
```

My first thought was that it might have been another script on the page interfering with `Math.floor`, so I started logging it's implementation.

Then, I wondered if it might be a floating point/overflow issue. The user agents suggest 32bit IE (`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2; rv:11.0) like Gecko`), but upon testing the above log in a VM from modern.ie, I got the expected result.

What might be going on here?

Comment: the answer to why might IE is usually because its IE

Comment: Math.floor seems to return a 32bit signed integer (Firefox can get the same result by doing `Math.floor(1442167625975 / 16) | 0` ) which proves IE **is** limited to 32bit in Math.floor)

Comment: Are you sure that Modern IE is also 32-bit?

Comment: the CPU shouldn't be a factor - except of course, Microsoft

Comment: I'm using IE and I get the correct floor. I plugged in 90135476623.4375/16 on the following site http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_floor

Comment: hmmm - I just checked in that version of IE, and got the correct result, not the one shown in the question

Comment: are you using your own math.floor definition?

Comment: I've seen similar issues with Math.floor not working,(Media Center PC 6.0 check Window NT 6.1 Check,  rv:11.0/Internet explorer 11 , check  Trident 7.0 check but my example also has a WOW64 user agent which definitively says IE32 but also don't know the exact cause, for me,